# How to check if MS teams app is shared in cisco webex meeting

Tags: c#, desktop-application, microsoft-teams, webex

I am writing a MS Teams plugin in C#. I need to act differently in my plugin code when MS Teams app is shared in Cisco Webex meeting as an app sharing. Can somebody help me how can I get to know in my plugin code (which is running in a separate process) when MS Teams is shared as screen sharing. Note this should apply only when screen sharing is done for single app and not entire desktop.

Are there any events that I can listen to or something on process level? If somebody can share a working code snippet that will be great. Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Let me know if you need more details. Thank you.

Comment: Currently there is no event you get from [Microsoft Teams App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview) side which it's getting shared.

Comment: Thanks for your asnswer. Do I get any event or footprint or any flag from Windows whenever my app window is screen shared?

Comment: Currently there is no event for footprint or flag.